# AVCam vs UIImagepicker

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation, avcam

I m new in iPhone, i want to know what is the difference b/w AVFoundation's AVCam and UIImagePicker for camera. When we should go for AVCam and when for UIImagePicker

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AVCam is just an example of how you can use AVFoundation to generate your own capture functions.

> AVCam demonstrates how to use the AV Foundation capture APIs for
>   recording movies and taking still images. There is a record button for
>   recording movies, a camera button for switching between front and back
>   cameras (on supported devices), and a still button for taking still
>   images. Next

so the difference between AVFoundation and ImagePicker:

Image Picker is like a customizable black box, you dont really have to do anything other than implement its delegate to get captured images from the camera, or the camera roll. Hence it is very easy to use, If you are looking for basic behavior then go for this one. Note that you can change the "Skin" of how it looks, there are tutorials about doing that on the web.

AVFoundation is the actual access to the iPhone camera, if you take this aproach you have to implement everything yourself (or copy the example and modify it accordingly). You will have to read the documentation carefully but the result is a lot more freedom in stuff you can do, this is usually used for image processing, camera with special functions, etc.

So what you really want to ask yourself is what level of customization you will need and chose accordingly.

(If you are new to ios in general go with the image picker)

Comment: My requirement is showing camera(for video and picture capture) with a button which can open ur's photo library.

Comment: why do you want to open the photo library while in camera mode?